# Include javascript on specific pages using Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets

I have created service for live chat using Ajax and Rails, where I send ajax GET requests to server and receive responds . Anyway, I want that Ajax script works on every page except on home/chat.
So, I have chat.js file and I include it in application.html like follow:

```
title Online Mental Health
 = stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => "all"
 = csrf_meta_tags
 = javascript_include_tag 'application'
 - unless params[:controller] == 'home' 
   = javascript_include_tag 'chat.js'
```

Also, I added in staging.rb and production.rb this :

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w( chat.js )
```

And I didn't include my chat.js file into application.js .

But when I deploy my application on server, and do

```
 RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exex rake assets:precompile
```

I am getting error as bellow:

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Dashboards#user_view

chat.js isn't precompiled

Extracted source (around line #10):

7:     / = render 'shared/chat_javascript_include'
8:     = javascript_include_tag 'application'
9:     - unless params[:controller] == 'home' 
10:       = javascript_include_tag 'chat.js' 
11:   body
12:     = render 'forum_areas/header'
13:   - if current_user.present?
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `config.assets.compile = true` did you try this

Comment: Yes, that's solve my problem . But I think that's not good practice to set assets.compile on true because performances ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make my comment as  a post for any one use it

Please do this in your environment file(`staging.rb` , `production.rb`)

`config.assets.compile = true`